# The use of pensare che / credere che vs. ritenere che (+ congiuntivo)

Tags: word-usage, verbs, difference

The verbs *pensare*, *credere*, and *ritenere* have similar meanings. However, are they always interchangeable?

*Pensare* is "to think" and *credere* is "to believe", but *ritenere* seems like 1. it is a word for a higher register, perhaps more formal and literary, and 2. is used for when you are referring to belief in principles rather than just plain thought.

Take for instance the sentence: "penso di usare la rete ogni giorno". This isn't a problematic sentence. But the sentence, "ritengo che lui usi il telefonino ogni cinque minuti" sounds pretentious. The expressed thought is also not a deep conviction, it is a simple thought, so the use of *ritenere* here doesn't seem correct.

Comment: If by “pretentious” you mean, as the vocabulary says, «attempting to impress by affecting greater importance or merit than is actually possessed», then no, using *ritenere* is not pretentious by itself. It is perhaps more usual, as you say, in a higher register (say, a speech or an essay), but it is not unheard even in everyday conversation.

Comment: Well, the sentence *ritengo che lui usi il telefonino ogni cinque minuti* is appropriate for a teacher sending a student to the director.

Answer (score 6):

*Ritenere* is generally used in a higher register, as DaG says, but I may say "ritengo di non farcela" if I want to convey the fact that I thought about it and I eventually decided that I cannot possibly do it. This is different from "penso/credo di non farcela", where I have a hunch that I won't be able to do it.

As for *penso/credo*, besides the liturgic Creed :-) the latter should reflect a bit more confidence, but in practice they are interchangeable.